# Why does setIsAnchor(1); and $category->save(); not work sometimes. when changing the category Anchor?

Tags: magento-1.8

Does anyone know why in some stores the save does not change the is_anchor and in some stores it does? It is not working on a multi-store site (multiple default root categories)., though there may be other reasons.

The code below generally works. When it does not it, the save has no effect, without any log errors.

$anchorNew has the correct value in it.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 1))
    ->setOrder('entity_id') ;

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $anchor = $category->getIsAnchor();
    if ($anchor == 1 ) {
        continue;
    }
    $category->setIsAnchor(1);
    $category->save(); 

    $anchorNew = $category->getIsAnchor(); // this shows a 1 in is_anchor
}
```

I checked the database and there are not as many entries in - `catalog_category_entity_int` 
 WHERE attribute_id = 51 - as there are categories. The $category->getIsAnchor() returns null for many of my categories.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the fact that you are calling `save` on a category object that comes from a collection. To be sure it works, you should always call `load` before calling `save`.

something like this:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $anchor = $category->getIsAnchor();
    if ($anchor == 1 ) {
        continue;
    }
    $category->load($category->getId());
    $category->setIsAnchor(1);
    $category->save(); 
}
```

I know it's not a good practice to call `load` in a loop, but neither is calling `save` in a loop.

Comment: In what instance would the category object from the collection not save properly with `save()`?

Comment: As long as the id is set in the object, you should be able to call save on it...

Comment: This solved my problem when saving sub-categories obtained by calling getChildrenCategories() on a parent category.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the reason is that you have ***Use Flat Catalog Category*** set to ***Yes*** and your code doesn't account for this scenario.

Try turning that setting off in ***System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend*** and then run the script again. When you switch flat catalog back on again, be sure to reindex the required tables.

Answer (score -2):

•   Create a php file, Add below content

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app();

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('is_anchor', 0)
 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("gt" => 1))
 ->setOrder('entity_id')
 ;

foreach($categories as $category) {

 $category->setIsAnchor(1);
 $category->save();
}

echo “Done”;
?>
```

- Upload to root of Magento server.
- Access the file from your web browser.

Comment: This does not even try to answer the question, *why* OP's code does not work as expected.